# Composer Dataflow job error using DataflowTempleOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, dataflow, google-cloud-composer, orchestration

I am trying to run standard GCS_Text to Bigquery standard template job using Composer and get http error shown below. I could successfully run and create the   job manually in Dataflow
Am I passing the parameter correctly?

```
ERROR - <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/XXXXXX/locations/xyz/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs%3A%2F%2Fdataflow-templates%2Flatest%2FGCS_Text_to_BigQuery&alt=json returned "The template parameters are invalid.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.dataflow.v1beta3.InvalidTemplateParameters', 'parameterViolations': [{'parameter': 'javascriptTextTransformFunctionName', 'description': 'Missing required parameter'}, {'parameter': 'TransformFunctionName', 'description': 'Unrecognized parameter'}, {'parameter': 'serviceAccount', 'description': 'Unrecognized parameter'}, {'parameter': 'project', 'description': 'Unrecognized parameter'}, {'parameter': 'subnetwork', 'description': 'Unrecognized parameter'}]}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are receiving is pretty clear. Some parameters (`project`, `subnetwork`, `service_account`, `TransformFunctionName`) are not recognised and `javascriptTextTransformFunctionName` is missing.

Check again the [documentation examples](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-dataflow-template-operator) on how to launch jobs with the `DataflowTemplateOperator` as well as [the docs for the operator itself](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator.DataflowTemplateOperator).

In a few words, `TransformFunctionName` should be renamed to `javascriptTextTransformFunctionName` and `project`, `subnetwork` and `service_account` should be removed from the `parameters` dict and specified in `dataflow_default_options` dict instead.

Comment: I'm happy I helped! Please accept the answer as the correct one according to the [community suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)